# PGP batch file to check user from list

Tags: batch-file

I want to store  **!output[%%n]! | findstr /c:"global"** in a variable. if a set this to something it doesn't working or create an if statement that check the word if it shows then echo it is here if not then it is not here.

```
@echo off 
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a:%%b)
for /f "usebackq" %%i IN (`hostname`) DO SET MYVAR=%%i

set cmpInfo=%mydate%, %mytime%, %MYVAR%
set cmd1="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\PGP Corporation\PGP Desktop"
set "output_cnt=0"


cd %cmd1%
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('pgpwde --list-user --disk 0') DO (
    set /a output_cnt+=1
    set "output[!output_cnt!]=%%a"
)

for /L %%n in (1 1 !output_cnt!) DO (
   **!output[%%n]! | findstr /c:"global"**
)

pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not real certain what you are trying to do but I am guessing this is what you want to do.

```
for /L %%n in (1 1 !output_cnt!) DO (
    echo !output[%%n]! | findstr /i /c:"global" >nul 2>&1 && echo yes || echo no
)
```

But I think you could also do something like this.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('pgpwde --list-user --disk 0') DO (
    set "output=%%a"
    if not "!output:global=!"=="!output!" (
        echo yes
    ) else (
        echo no
    )
)
```

Comment: @B3t0, please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: one more question about this, this returns a list like this: no no no no yes no no no, because pgpwde --list-user --disk 0 returns a list of users and the user global is there. I just want to store the answer in a variable now. if yes do something if not then do something else. If user global is there or not.

Comment: Change `echo yes` and `echo no` to whatever you want to do.